# Break down versions into an integer - SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to break down versions into integers.

for example,
from 14.4 to 14
or from 9.4.1 to 9

How can I define the number until the dot?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this in a database by looking up the server version? If so: `select substring(current_setting('server_version_num') from 1 for 2)::int; 14`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try SPLIT_PART
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html

```
select Split_part(column1,'.',0) col1 from values ('14.4') ,('9.4.1') , ('12345.5656')
```